# How to have just 1 approve in phantom when try to create several NFTs at the the same time?

Tags: metaplex, nft

I'm trying to create a feature on my web page where the user is able to create their own collection of nfts. To make these I follow these workflow:

1. The user want to create a collection of 5000 nfts for example
2. I create the arweave link of every nfts using bundlr (mostly using the [uploadAll](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js/blob/8164eb89bf551f31c90ee25b6c2b79f23384200a/src/plugins/bundlrStorage/BundlrStorageDriver.ts#L105) method of metaplex)
3. I create the nft (mostly using the [metaplex.nfts().create()](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#create) method)

My code is something like these:

To make 2)

```
// I upload all the images (pngs)
console.log("procesing images", metaplexFiles)
const imageLinks = await metaplex.storage().uploadAll(metaplexFiles)

// Later on I put the images inside the json and create the arweaveLinks
  metaplexFiles = filePairs.map(({manifest}) => manifest as MetaplexFile)
  console.log("A metaplex file", metaplexFiles)
  const arweaveLinks = await metaplex.storage().uploadAll(metaplexFiles)
```

[image]

These simple code gives me 3 approvals

1 of these

[image]

And 2 of these

[image]

To make 3)

I use a code like these

```
 /**
 * Mint assets  with the metaplex SDK
 */
export async function mintNfts( collectionNFt: Nft, arweaveLinks: string[], wallet: WalletContextState, connection: Connection): Promise<Nft[]> {
  const metaplex = getMetaplexConfig(connection, wallet)

  const { results } = await PromisePool.withConcurrency(20)
  .for(arweaveLinks)
  .handleError(async (err) => {
    console.log(`Could not complete the transaction successfully, exiting due to:`, err);
    throw err;
  })
  .onTaskFinished((user, pool) => {
    // retrieve the number of items processed in the pool
    console.log(`${pool.processedCount()}/${arweaveLinks.length} proccesed`)
  })
  .process(async (link) => {
    console.log("creating an NFT")
    const { nft } = await metaplex.nfts().create({
      uri: link,
      isMutable: true,
      collection: {
        verified: false,
        key: collectionNFt.mint
      }
    });
    return nft;
  })

  return results;
}
```

That gives me just these approval

[image]

The final code will look like these

```
const arweaveLinks = await upload(files, nftForm.licence, wallet, connection);
// console.log("arweaveLinks", arweaveLinks);

const nfts = await mintNfts(collectionNft, arweaveLinks, wallet, connection);
```

These number of transaction that I show is **just for 1 NFT** the problem is that if the number of NFTs increases the number of transactions to approve increases too, so if the user want to mint around 1000 NFTs will have to approve more than 1000 popups of phantom.

These is my problem, I want to find a way to make all these workflow with as many as approves as possible, maybe with 1 o max 3 approves...
There is a way to make these?

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Frank there are a couple of ways in which the problem outlined here can be solved.
Since you are using Bundlr to upload it will ask you everytime to upload the asset and the arweave url is something that cannot be determined before hand so if you plan to do it from an UI than unfortunately the user has to go through that pain to solve particularly this problem you can either use IPFS to store asset image and metadata as it does not required signing or if you really wanna use arweave for storage than you can have a Backend service that does the signing on behalf of the user and pay some sol from the backend for covering the upload costs.

For Minting many NFT at once you need to make sure all the minting ix that you have added in the transaction are less than 1232 bytes and i think it would only allow 1-2 NFTs with this amount of bytes one work around for this can be to have a backend service which airdrops NFT to the user wallet in multiple transaction. In doing this the user does not have to sign a transaction multiple times its the backend service that will do that so makes the experience better.

Comment: So these problem of the approve to generate the arweave links is because of bundlr ? 

So in general the best approach to these is do a backend service that does all these work...

Comment: Ya arweave uses bundlr and bundlr needs some SOL to upload your file and give you links you can either take this process to your backend or use some other storage method

Comment: The problem that I'm seeing with this approach is that when comes the moment to transfer the NFTs in bulk from our wallet to the wallet of the user, don't will be problematic? 
I have try to send NFTs in bulk before and it's a little of problematic, sometimes gives an error...

Comment: Ya bulk transfer is multiple transfer ix in one transaction and the transaction object has a limit of 1232 bytes as of now which would be overcome by lookup tables which is still a work in progress.So you have to transfer n number of NFTs within the limit of 1232 bytes unfortunately.